# Como sumar en Javascript, la posición de un Array

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un pequeño trabajo en javascript. Muestra los partidos del dia, el tema está en la hora, la tengo almacenada en un array,  y cuando la muestro, quiero que sume `i + 1` pero aca me da error:

```
<h4 ><u>LaLiga (España) - 04/10/2020</u></h4>
<h5>"+dta[i]+"    Osasuna -  Celta de Vigo </h5>
<a class='waves-effect waves-light btnoutlinelight outline ahref' href='"+url+"test/statistics?url=https://m.livesoccertv.com/es/match/3757239/osasuna-vs-celta-de-vigo/ ' style='background-color: #ffffff00;'><b>Estadisticas</b></a> 
<h5>"+dta[i+1]+"  Deportivo Alavés -  Athletic Club </h5>
<a class='waves-effect waves-light btnoutlinelight outline ahref' href='"+url+"test/statistics?url=https://m.livesoccertv.com/es/match/3757234/deportivo-alaves-vs-athletic-club/ ' style='background-color: #ffffff00;'><b>Estadisticas</b></a> 
<h5>"+dta[i+1]+"  Levante -  Real Madrid </h5>
<a class='waves-effect waves-light btnoutlinelight outline ahref' href='"+url+"test/statistics?url=https://m.livesoccertv.com/es/match/3757238/levante-vs-real-madrid/ ' style='background-color: #ffffff00;'><b>Estadisticas</b></a> 
<h5>"+dta[i+1]+"  Cádiz -  Granada </h5>
<a class='waves-effect waves-light btnoutlinelight outline ahref' href='"+url+"test/statistics?url=https://m.livesoccertv.com/es/match/3757237/cadiz-vs-granada/ ' style='background-color: #ffffff00;'><b>Estadisticas</b></a> 
<h5>"+dta[i+1]+"  Barcelona -  Sevilla </h5>
<a class='waves-effect waves-light btnoutlinelight outline ahref' href='"+url+"test/statistics?url=https://m.livesoccertv.com/es/match/3757236/barcelona-vs-sevilla/ ' style='background-color: #ffffff00;'><b>Estadisticas</b></a>
```

`i` la inicializo en 0, y en la primero no sumo nada, y despues en las 3 siguientes ya a `i` le sumo 1, pero asi no funciona, supongo porque el `+` se usa para concatenar.
Todo está en Javascript, en un InnerHTML, solo que aqui lo acomodé para que se entienda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:
`"+dta[i=i+1]+"` así `i` si suma en sucesivamente hasta que termine el script.
No se si sea la forma mas correcta, pero aqui nadie puso nada. Asi que por ahora dejo esto.